# Update Score of logged in user MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

For learning purposes I'm playing with php/mysql. I've got a scenario where I have a number of users, games and scores.

I've created a page where users can login and edit there details. However I would like them to able to add a score as well now. I've tried to apply the logic from the user details updating but that didn't work for me. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome. You can find the snippets of the page and update script here:

User dashbaord:
http://www.smipple.net/snippet/spiritonline/User%20dashboard

Update score script:
http://www.smipple.net/snippet/spiritonline/update_score

My DB is formatted as follows:

tables: Gebruikers, Score & spellen

Gebruikers has the following fields:

```
Gebruikersnaam                                       
Wachwoord                                    
Achternaam                                   
Voornaam                                         
Tussenvoegsel                                        
Avatar                               
Geboortedatum                               
Geslacht                                    
Email
```

Score has the following fields:

```
ID           
Score        
Game_ID      
User_ID      
Datum
```

Spellen has the following fields:

```
ID
Naam
```

If someone could point me in right direction that would be awesome! :)

Comment: State exactly what problems do you face?

Comment: That would be the right direction of what?

Comment: What is your main problem, how far you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

To get you started:

```
INSERT INTO Score (Score,Game_ID,User_ID,Datum) VALUES ($score,$gameid,$userid,NOW());
```

Of course, the variables `$score`etc. have to be properly sanitized and put into appropriate quotes. You can use `PDO`to handle mysql and have `PDO`take care of this.